# Nuxt 3 Composables inside nuxt.config.ts

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I created a composable to load api data via graphql, using nuxt-graphql-client

I have this in my /composables/useMyData.ts

```
export const useMyData = async () => {
  const { data } = await useAsyncGql({
    operation: 'myData',
    variables: { handle: 'myVariable' }
  })
  return data
}
```

and then I can access it on app.vue like this:

```
<script setup>
  const mydata = await useMyData()
</script>
```

So far so good, but there are cases where I would like to use some of that data in app settings inside `defineNuxtConfig({ })` of `nuxt.config.ts`.

For example meta tags in `head:` and to populate the .webmanifest via `pwa` settings (using @vite-pwa/nuxt).

would that be popssible?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Nuxt this is not possible, because when Nuxt starts up, it first reads everything from `nuxt.config.ts` to initialise itself.

However, for Meta tags, there are special Nuxt components that can be used on the page itself: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta

Example: `<Meta name="description" :content="title" />`

Alternative:
To populate `nuxt.config.ts` with dynamic data, you could also do a GraphQL request outside of Nuxt and store the answer in a file. Then you import that file into the nuxt config.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot directly use a Nuxt 3 composable in the nuxt.config.ts file, The nuxt.config.ts is specifically for configuring your Nuxt settings and options. It is not intended for writing JavaScript code or using composables.